# ks test for uniform distribution in range -1 to 1 in R

Tags: r

I have implemented a simple version of the congruential method, and now I want to test if the generated numbers are distributed uniformly using the KS test.

First I did a simple test

```
R.ks_test(U1, "punif")
```

but this gave an incredible small p-value. Then I realised that my congruential method yields numbers in the range of -1 to 1, and I suspect the default ks test in R checks for uniformity between 0 and 1.

**Can I tell R to check for uniformity between -1 and 1, or should I simply just scale my values to be between 0 and 1?**

*I am using the [R type provider in F#](https://bluemountaincapital.github.io/FSharpRProvider/) but it shouldn't make much of a difference*

*..and sorry if this is a simple question, my statistics kungfu is incredible weak :)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the parameters of your distribution into the `ks.test`. Here is an example for testing the uniform (-1,1) distribution.

```
x<-runif(100,-1,1)
ks.test(x,"punif",-1,1)




 One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
        data:  x
        D = 0.082848, p-value = 0.4986
        alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Αnd here is a visualization of the test.

```
  library(ggplot2)
    set.seed(1)
    x<-runif(100,-1,1)
    dd<-data.frame(x)
    ks.test(x,"punif",-1,1)

    ed <- ecdf(dd$x)
    maxdiffidx <- which.max(abs(ed(dd$x)-punif(dd$x,-1,1)))
    maxdiffat <- dd$x[maxdiffidx]

    p<-ggplot(aes(x),data=dd)+stat_ecdf()+theme_bw()+stat_function(fun=punif,args=list(-1,1))
    p<-p+labs(title="ECDF and theoretical CDF")+geom_vline(x=maxdiffat, lty=2)
    p
```

[image]

The vertical line corresponds to the maximum distance between the ECDF and the theoretical CDF, which is the KS statistic.

The `ks.test` can be adapted to test for whichever distribution you like by adding the proper arguments, just like I have done above. This will give you what you are looking for, I believe.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Just an update. It should be (maybe this is new as this answer is already some years old): `p<-
  labs(title="ECDF and theoretic)al CDF"+
  geom_vline(xintercept=maxdiffat, lty=2)`. Else you get an error if u use `x` instead of `xintercept`.